# sorting elements File[] array

Tags: java, sorting

I'm trying to sort filenames that's in `fList` array. Originally `fList` is sorted like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCqJR.jpg and after result https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgBsq.jpg

I wanted the result sorted according to their preceding number before the filename like so:

- 1. Selenium Introduction
- 2. Complete Installation Guide for java and Selenium Learning
- 3. Brush up Java Concepts for Selenium Automation
- 4. CORE JAVA In depth for Manual testers and Beginners

...

- 38. Bonus!! Student Special

I have `something()` method to get the number from `fList[x]` filename to later compare when doing the `swap(fList[x], fList[y])` as you can tell from output console.
I'm not sure I understand how `File[]` actually stores and changes its elements

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("pathToFolder");
        File[] fList = file.listFiles();
        for(int x = 0; x < fList.length; x++) {
            int numberX = something(fList[x]);
            for(int y = x; y < fList.length; y++) {
                int numberY = something(fList[y]);
                if(numberX > numberY) {
                    File temp = fList[x];
                    fList[x] = fList[y];
                    fList[y] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x < fList.length; x++) {         
            System.out.println(fList[x].getName());
        }

    }

    static int something(File file) {
        String temp = file.getName();
        String number = "";
        for(int st = 0; st < temp.length(); st++) {
            if(temp.charAt(st) == '.') break;
            number += temp.charAt(st);
        }
        int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(number); 
        return fileNumber;
    }
```

Comment: You're caching `numberX` but not updating it when you swap.

Comment: No, it's an easy enough mistake to make.

Comment: Why not just call the [Arrays.sort overload](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator) that takes a Comparator and convert you `something` method into a `Comparator.compare` method?

Comment: Your code can be also written as `Arrays.sort( fList, Comparator.comparing( File::getName, Comparator.comparingInt( name -> Integer.parseInt( name.split("\\.")[0] ) ) ) )` OR using your `something` method `Arrays.sort( fList, Comparator.comparingInt(YourClassName::something) );`

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you're using `Java8`, you can of course tweak it to match your requirements:

```
List<File> sortedFiles = stream(requireNonNull(file.listFiles()))
            .sorted(File::compareTo)
            .collect(toList());
```

You can use also the `sort` method provided by the class `Arrays`:

```
File[] sortedFiles = file.listFiles();
    // One liner
    Arrays.sort(sortedFiles);
```

> Both of the solution rely on the implementation of the `compareTo` from the `File` class. [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#compareTo(java.io.File)) to the official documentation.

I added a test in my personal [git repo](https://github.com/AElMehdi/Code-Challenges/blob/master/src/test/java/stackoverflow/FilesSortingTest.java)

Answer (score 0):

How about below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("pathToFolder");
    File[] fList = file.listFiles();
    Map<Integer, File> fileMap = new TreeMap<Integer, File>();
    for (int x = 0; x < fList.length; x++) {
        int numberX = something(fList[x]);
        fileMap.put(numberX, fList[x]);
    }

    fileMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println((v.getName())));

}

static int something(File file) {
    String temp = file.getName();
    String number = temp.split("\\.")[0];
    int fileNumber = Integer.parseInt(number);
    return fileNumber;
}
```

Comment: Your solution may work for OPs use case. But I wouldnt add a map just to sort files. Besides if there are two files with the same number, e.g. `1. CORE JAVA` and `1. CORE C++` using your approach will loose one of the files as you cann't have duplicate keys in map.